# XLib Asynchronous Event Handling (Without XBC)

Tags: c++, multithreading, xlib

With xlib in c++ is there a way to asynchronously handle events? `XNextEvent` blocks until an event arrives. Is the only way of doing this calling `XNextEvent` from a different thread? I am aware that XCB is in development and will support concurrency (I think?) but I need to do this with just xlib for education. Thanks :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check for events with `XPending`.
It doesn't block.

```
while (XPending(dpy))
{
    XEvent ev;
    XNextEvent(dpy, &ev);
    ....
    if (ev.type == KeyPress)
    {
        ....
    }
}
```